# messages are being sent which I am not aware from my I phone leading to deduction of balance

Tags: messages

I am not sending smses but am being charged for the sms being sent to some ISD number from my I Phone 4s. The number and message text supposedly sent does not appear in the sent items. How to stop messages being automatically sent to this number from my phone?
Service provider IDEA in UP.
Can anyone help solve this issue please?

Comment: Some message apps send sms for initial activation. I think imessage sends one sms as well when it is activated. How many sms are being sent? What number are the sms sent to? You could find out more if you google it.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to contact your carrier for information about charges. They will know the specifics of your contract and options as well as help you by asking some questions like

- What version of iOS are you running?
- Are you using iMessage?

Your first step might be disabling SMS on the iPhone and then contacting the carrier to get further instructions. It really depends upon what number is sending the SMS and if you opted in to any subscriptions or [got crammed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramming_(fraud)) or signed in to SMS on a web service of some sort.